# Can't decrypt text that doesn't end with equal "="

Tags: c#, encryption, base64

I can encrypt just fine. However, if an encrypted string doesn't end with the equal letter "=" at the end, then it won't decrypt properly and I get an empty string (or so it seems).

What works:

> +FmU/RQ5jP86j7F6bPjddA==
>
> YQXBLjwEXEGgYz8xnF10O9QqO/vj5DI8PpZZCvfhG1RGHAYumtWrAEBfdSSOkF79vzVCSQ+ejO3uMIDSmY43bw==

What won't work:

> xnyfqPsvrEOK8AoQz2p7AGFHoHncZ/wB/R3qr+scts6nLI2xauWnbmYsXsU3iMoT

encrypt function:

```
    public string EncryptionKey = "abc123";


    public string encrypt(string input)
    {           
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                input = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Here's the decrypt function:

```
   public string decrypt(string cipherText)
    {

        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT: Added encrypt function**

**EDIT 2:**

This is how I'm calling the encrypt-function (before I send the string via socket.io)

```
 ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] sendMsg = new byte[1500];
 sendMsg = aEncoding.GetBytes((encrypt(txtMsg.Text)));
```

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I see, then I guess it's the encrypt-function (I added it above) that makes an invalid base64 string?

Comment: just read my answer, but if you can't understand it, your answer is simple - YOU CAN'T DO THIS if encrypted string comes with "=" or "==" chars in the end.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? I'm pretty sure the '=' thing is a red herring -- the failing string is a valid base64-encoded string.

Comment: is it original text: 鄺ੁ﯍톋螟⢹ⲰⳞ蘮읝赂厚᨟בֿ䔋⊮  ?

Comment: @MaciejS. No it's not. I can't recall what it was.

Comment: was your encrypted string in any Asian dialect? maybe your decrypting function is OK, but I don't have installed some components... generally I got exception while running your decrypt function and had to delete `cs.Close();` line (this is known bug discussed in MSDN forums and solved by custom overriden function). but my output wasn't empty string...

Answer (score 2):

I will not give you full answer and make any lecture of cryptography, because it's huge topic.
Answer for Your question is simple - it will not work without "=" or "==" characters on the end as long as you are using `Convert.FromBase64String` function, becuase those chars are characteristic to this encoding.
More information under this link in "Output padding" section: [Base64 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
Conclusion: if encrypted string comes with mentioned chars, it can't be decrypted without it.

Comment: Even the output padding section you mention shows valid strings that do not require = or == padding.

Comment: yes, that's true, but read carefully mentioned article or Base64 RFC.

Comment: Thanks, I see why it none "=" string won't work. Any idea how to solve this? I'm new to this and have no idea how to solve this.